# How to get all possible delinations of field into a matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have this field:

[image]

What I want is to get all the potential delinations of this field. But there is a restriction, a delination must consist of only neighbor quarters. That means we can't have a delination of 1st-4th quarter and 2nd-3rd quarter. The number of the potential delinations is given by this formula:

|N| = $$(\sum_{i=1}^{Width-MinWidth+1} i)(\sum_{i=1}^{Length-MinLength+1} i)$$ ,

where Width equals the width of the field, Length equals the length of the field (in this case both are 2), MinWidth equals the minimum width of a zone and MinLength equals the minimum length of a zone (in this case they can be 1 or 2).

So, if MinWidth = 1 and MinLength = 1, in this example |N| = 9.

I would like to have the rectangular zones of this field in a corresponding matrix. This corresponding matrix for this example will have to look like this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1
 [5,]    1    1    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    1    1
 [7,]    1    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    1    0    1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1
```

The interpretation of this matrix is that the first delination consists of the 1st quarter only (and 2,3,4 together), the second delination consists of the 2nd quarter only (and 1,3,4 together), ... , the fifth delination consists of the 1st and 2nd quarter (and 3,4 together), and so it goes on. The matrix for a 3x3 field would be a 36x9 matrix, similar to the one above.

I have managed to build a loop that interates |N| times (the number of the potential delineations), the code is below:

```
z <- 0
  for (j in MinWidth:Width) {
    for (l in 0:(Width - 1)) {
      if ((j + l) <= Width) {
        for (i in MinLength:Length) {
          for (k in 0:(Length-1)) {
            if ((k + i) <= Length) {
              z <- z + 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What this loop does is:

It takes the quarters and then checks if there is remaining space, first widthwise and then lengthwise, to create a zone.
j stands for the Width, l stands for the available width remaining, i stand for the Length and k stands for the available length remaining. But I can't get the right rows of the matrix for every loop.

Are there any ides how can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a convoluted solution (it can certainly be optimized) be it does return your matrix with only base R. Just enter mat(l,w) where l and w describe the length and width of your field:

```
library(nnls)

expand <- function(x) {
  out = x
  index = which(is.na(x))
  for(i in 1:length(index)) {
    y = x[(index[i]+1):length(x)]
    add = length(x)-length(y)
    out = rbind(out,c(y,rep(NA,add)))
  }
  return(out)
}

check_split <- function(M) {
  check = c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(M)) {
    Y = ifelse(M[i,] == 1,0,1)
    mod = round(coef(nnls(t(M[-i,]),matrix(Y))),10)
    mod[is.na(mod)] = 0
    check = c(check,all(mod %in% c(1,0)))
  }
  return(check)
}

mat <- function(l,w,minL,minW) {
  print(matrix(1:(l*w),byrow=T,nrow=l))

  out = list()
  x=c()
  for(i in 1:(l*w)) {
    if(i%%w == 0){
      x = c(x,i,NA)
    } else {
      x = c(x,i)
    }
  }

  y = expand(x)
  for (m in 1:l) {
    y = expand(x)[1:m,]
    for (n in 0:w) {
      for (i in 1:length(x)) {
        if(m == 1) {
        out = c(out,list(y[i:(i+n)]))
        } else {
          out = c(out,list(y[,i:min((i+n),ncol(y))]))
        }
      }
    }
  }

allCombinations = out[unlist(lapply(out,function(x) !any(is.na(x))))]
allCombinations = lapply(allCombinations,as.matrix,byrow=T)
allCombinations = lapply(allCombinations,function(x) if(ncol(x)==1 & is.null(rownames(x))){t(x)}else{x})

## Account for restrictions
lengths = lapply(allCombinations, nrow)
widths = lapply(allCombinations, ncol)
simple = lapply(allCombinations, function(x) sort(as.vector(x)))[lengths >= minL & widths >= minW]

## Desired matrix
output = do.call(rbind, lapply(simple, function(x) ifelse(1:(l*w) %in% x, 1,0)))

output[check_split(output),]

}
```

Happy to answer questions if there is confusion.

Comment: That is amazing, really. I will try to understand the code and come back to you. Something more, once we have the matrix C, how could we delete rows based on minimum width and minimum length in our Field. For example, if minimum width must be 2, then we get only 3 possible delinations.

Comment: This is easily done with the allCombinations object since it preserves the dimensions of the subdivisions. I edited the answer above to include minimum restrictions.

Comment: If we type mat(3,3,2,2), then we get 9 possible delinations. However, in this case we should take only 1, since, for example, in the first possible delination we get a zone with 1-2-4-5 and the rest quarters are 3-6-9-7-8. So, the remaining quarters don't follow the restriction. The only delination that follows this restriction is the whole field itself.

Comment: I forgot to mention you before

Comment: I see now, you want the partition to satisfy the restrictions. I believe the revised answer will do that--it requires that you install the nnls package: ```install.packages("nnls")```. Although, obviously, there are many other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: One last thing. If we type mat(2,2,2,1), then we get 3 possible delinations. But we have to get 2, since getting 1,3 and 2,4 is actually counted twice. My mistake not realizing that before.